# Multiple Line series on single chart control

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts, time-series

I want to show the second line series underneath the first one, however with this code they are appearing sequentially. Not sure how to make sure they are overlayed! I followed some code I saw for combining charts.. not sure what to do.

```
<mx:LineChart  showDataTips="true" x="10" y="77" id="GlucoseChart"  width="1009" height="219">
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:DateTimeAxis dataUnits="hours" parseFunction="parseDateString" displayLocalTime="true" />
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries id="glucoseSeries" radius="8" form="curve" displayName="BG" yField="Value" xField="DateTime">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:CircleItemRenderer />
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:LineSeries>

        <mx:LineSeries radius="2" id="glucoseOverlaySeries1" yField="Value" xField="DateTime" interactive="false">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:CircleItemRenderer />
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:LineSeries>
    </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine:

Check this app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            private static function createData(num:int):Array
            {
                var i:int;
                var arr:Array = new Array();
                var now:Date = new Date();
                now = new Date(now.fullYear, now.month, now.date);
                var curr:Date;
                var o:Object;
                var val:Number;
                for (i=0; i< num; i++)
                {
                    curr = new Date(
                        now.fullYear, 
                        now.month, 
                        now.date - (num - i - 1)
                        )
                    val = Math.random()*100;
                    o = new Object();
                    o.DateTime = curr;
                    o.Value = val;
                    arr.push(o);
                }
                return arr;
            }

            [Bindable]
            private var glucoseSeriesData:Array = createData(14);
            [Bindable]
            private var glucoseSeriesData1:Array = createData(14);


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:LineChart  showDataTips="true" x="10" y="77" id="GlucoseChart"  width="1009" height="219">
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:DateTimeAxis dataUnits="days" displayLocalTime="true" />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:series>
            <mx:LineSeries id="glucoseSeries" radius="8" form="curve" displayName="BG" 
                           yField="Value" xField="DateTime"
                           dataProvider="{glucoseSeriesData}"
                           >
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <mx:CircleItemRenderer />
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:LineSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries radius="2" id="glucoseOverlaySeries1" 
                           yField="Value"  xField="DateTime" 
                           interactive="false"
                           dataProvider="{glucoseSeriesData1}"
                           >
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <mx:CircleItemRenderer />
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:LineSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:LineChart> 

</s:Application>
```

I'm prety sure there's something wrong in your data. Data shoould have the same xValues ranges for both series.

Comment: yeah as soon as you said that it kinda clicked.. the data is from two different days.. I want to overlay them, but technically they *are* sequential... I was going around assuming the chart is based off just the time and not the date (wish it was!) so I guess I'll have to write some loops to add 1 day to the datetime values of the overlaydata array.. unless there's some way i can modify the graph to accomodate it.

Comment: @Damon Your code initially contained parseFunction, which I removed as it was useless in my example. The parseFunction is the way you can convert input date to axis date. i.e. In your case parseFunction can accept Date values, and convert them to specific Date values where for example date information is zeroed and only time remains.

Comment: that mighta been easier.. although since i want to cover a 24 hour period that could cross from one date to the other, perhaps it's best that I did it the way I did (a for loop to assign all the dates to the original one)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this: [Multiple Chart Areas in .Net](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/documentation/v3_2/Multiple%20Chart%20Areas.html).

I was looking for the same in Flex a while back but could not find a way of doing it. I ended up instantiating two LineCharts and placing them inside a VBox and not declaring a horizontal axis for the first one so that it looks like the two are sharing the same x-axis (of the lower one). You will need to assign the same value of gutterLeft to the two so that the vertical axis align correctly.

Comment: ah I had hacked it that way before and found it very difficult to align them properly.. I will try again with those pointers. will probably use variables for their position to make it smoother.